# smtp error on sending email : sender address must contain a domain

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

hi i get this error when i try to send email

```
SMTP -> ERROR: MAIL not accepted from server: 501 : sender address must contain a domain
```

it used to work fine i'm not sure what happend
i use php mailer but i dont think this is important

```
   $smtp = setting::get_smtp( 1 , 'support');      

   $mail   = new PHPMailer(); 
   $mail->IsSMTP(); 
   $mail->Host       = $smtp->address;  //localhost
   $mail->CharSet    = "utf-8";                              
   $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                 
   $mail->Port       = $smtp->port;    // 25                  
   $mail->Username   = $smtp->username; 
   $mail->Password   = $smtp->password;   
   $mail->From       =  $smtp->from ; // www.mysite.com
   $mail->AddReplyTo ($smtp->username , $smtp->from ); // noreply@mysite.com //www.mysite.com
   $mail->Subject    = $title;
   $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; 

       $mail->MsgHTML($msg);
       $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
       if( filter_var( $admin_email , FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) == TRUE ){
       $mail->AddAddress($admin_email , "John Doe");
           $mail->Send();
       }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is a bit misleading, but the problem is clear.  The `From:` header must contain a domain as a complete email address.  If your `$smtp->from` contains `www.mysite.com`, that is an invalid email address, missing the part after `@`.  The mailer misinterprets your domain name as only the first part of an email address (the user part) and complains that it needs `@domain` to go with it.  Supply a full sender email address to your `$smtp->from` property.

```
 // Should be something like sender@example.com
 $mail->From       =  $smtp->from ;
```

Comment: thank this is it but , it's kinda weird i can vividly remember it used to work with anything

Comment: @max The SMTP server which is actually delivering the messages may have gotten more strict about the contents of the From header.  The error reported originates from the SMTP server, and is relayed to you by PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't $mail->From be set to an email address?